# Most efficient way to convert a object to another (Model to ViewModel)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

Suppose I have a model with 20 fields, and in my index page, I want to list all models that are stored in my database.
In index page, instead of listing all fields of the model, I only to list 3 fields.

So, I make two class:

```
class CompleteModel {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Field01 { get; set; }
    public string Field02 { get; set; }
    public string Field03 { get; set; }
    public string Field04 { get; set; }
    public string Field05 { get; set; }
    ...
    public string Field20 { get; set; }
}
```

now, in my Controller, I can use:

```
await _context.CompleteModel.ToListAsync();
```

but I feel that it does not seem to be the right way to do it, because I'm getting all fields and using only 3 fields.

So, I made this code:

```
class ViewModel {
    public string Field02 { get; set; }
    public string Field04 { get; set; }
    public string Field08 { get; set; }
}

var result = _context.CompleteModel.Select(
    x => new {
        x.Field02,
        x.Field04,
        x.Field08
    }).ToListAsync();

var listResults = new List<IndexViewModel>();
if (result != null)
{
    listResults.AddRange(results.Select(x => new IndexViewModel
    {
        Field02 = x.Field02,
        Field04 = x.Field04,
        Field08 = x.Field08
    }));
}
```

I think this is a lot of code to do this.
First, I selected all the fields that I want, then, copied everything to another object.

There's a "more directly" way to do the same thing?

Like:

```
_context.CompleteModel.Select(x => new IndexViewModel { Field02, Field04, Field08 });
```

Comment: Are you fetching all 20fields value? Or only selected ones as 2,4 and 8?

Comment: `efficient`?  code, performance (compute v. transport), memory?

Comment: You can skip the intermediate `.Select()` and use `List<IndexViewModel> model = _context.CompleteModel.Select(x => new IndexViewModel(){ Field02 = x.Field02, Field04 = x.Field04, ..... }.ToList();`

Comment: @MatthewWhited memory. ps: my example is much more simple than the real application.

Comment: thanks @StephenMuecke. Tried and worked good without a third party package (like AutoMapper) for this example.

Comment: AutoMapper isn't going to improve performance or memory usage.  It is only going to make code look somewhat cleaner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started) to reduce the boiler plate so you're not manually copying field values over.

If you include the AutoMapper NuGet package then you'd need to have the following in your startup somewhere to configure it for your classes:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<CompleteModel, ViewModel>());
```

You could then do something like the following:

```
var results = await _context.CompleteModel.ToListAsync();
var viewModelResults = results.Select(Mapper.Map<ViewModel>).ToList();
```

There are a lot of configuration options for the package so do take a look at the documentation to see if it suits your needs and determine the best way to use it if it does.

Comment: I was going to suggest this as well, although I wouldn't suggest using AutoMapper since its really slow. Use one of the newer object mappers that are MSIL based (TinyMapper, FastMapper, etc), those are like 10x faster then AutoMapper.

Comment: Thanks @SledgeHammer, I'll check those out! I think the main point is to use a library to automate the boilerplate code wherever possible so that we developers can concentrate on the fun code :)

Comment: @SledgeHammer: FastMapper doesn't seem to be actively maintained, 2 years no update, very unlikely it will get .NET Core support any time soon. No opened issue also suggest that not many people may use it and that itt still may be full of bugs due to it. Performance isn't an issue in 99% of the cases where AutoMapper is used. You'll never use it on a 1 or 10 million rows result set, you maybe wouldn't even want to use EF  here neither. At best you return 100-200 results and use paging

Comment: @Tseng - in a high volume environment, you can easily map 1M+ objects per day or even per hour. In my testing, a simple class with AutoMapper takes 13 *SECONDS* for AutoMapper vs. 60 *MILLISECONDS* for an IL mapper. IL Mapper is generally 1:1 with hand crafted code. Yup, I used the cached AutoMapper :), it's just that AutoMapper is extremely slow. It is powerful, but slow. But yeah, 13 seconds of overhead per hour is not that big of deal :), but better to be faster.

Comment: @SledgeHammer: I'd take a bit slower, but actively maintained library over a fast one w/o support/maintenance/active development (which only brings 0.1% more considering the duration of the whole request). Using an product that's not maintained will cost you more in the long run then the costs you save from a little performance. Premature micro-optimizations are the root of all evil

Comment: @Tseng Ok, well, here is an IL mapper that has .NET CORE support and is actively maintained and still kicks AutoMappers ass :) http://www.expressmapper.org/#benchmarks

Answer (score 4):

In my view this is one of the weaknesses of over abstraction and layering. The VM contains the data that is valuable to your application within the context of use (screen, process etc). The data model contains all the data that could be stored that might be relevant. At some point you need to match the two.

Use EF Projection to fetch only the data you need from the database into projected data model classes (using the EF POCO layer to define the query, but not to store the resultant data).

Map the projected classes onto your VM, if there is a naieve mapping, using Automapper or similar. However unless you are just writing CRUD screens a simple field by field mapping is of little value; the data you fetch from your data store via EF is in its raw, probably relational form. The data required by your VM is probably not going to fit that form very neatly (again, unless you are doing a simple CRUD form), so you are going to need to add some value by coding the relationship between the data store and the View Model.

I think concentrating on the count of lines of code would lead to the wrong approach. I think you can look at that code and ask "is it adding any value". If you can delegate the task to Automapper, then great; but your VM isn't really pulling its weight other than adding some validation annotation if you can consistently delegate the task of data model to VM data copying.

Comment: @RafaelMarques yes - this is the point I was making. People who use Automapper as a "solution" are missing the point. If you can Auto-map it, its not adding any value, and your VM is likely to be very little different from your data model - in which case all you've done is replicate Microsoft Access.

Comment: @PhillipH EXTREMELY false. AutoMapper doesn't just map a class to the same class. It can map to "light" versions, different naming conventions, to remove certain attributes (i.e. WCF), to FLATTEN, to PROJECT, to combine properties in more complex ways, convert types, etc. it does it all automatically. It is your naïve understanding of it if all you think it does is 1:1 mapping.

Comment: AutoMapper won't reduce the object or the data pulled from the database.  If you want to reduce those things you need to use proper ViewModel and use EF projection as Philip suggested.

Comment: @SledgeHammer - again, I am not saying "dont use a mapping tool" but that a mapping tool does just 'what it says on the tin' - it maps. It might introduce some nice new mapping semantics to the extent that its (yet)another query language on top of all the other query protocols, but all its doing it pulling data from one set of classes to another in a delcarative way. In my experience many VMs need data translating from their Data Models in a non-declarative way and that means writing some procedural code. Mappers are great for some circumstances, but cannot cover all the cases.